# Understanding of the chi square statistic

Tags: reliability

I have a formula for approximating the max the mean time between failures (MTBF) that is:
**r / operating time** (*note-MTBF is 1/ failure rate)
 where r is the number of failures observed. 
I have another formula that says 
**r~ chi^2(alpha,deg of freedom)/2**
My source states that using the chi square function gives a "more statistically accurate answer" for the MTBF or failure rate.

Can someone explain why this might be the case. I have a basic knowledge of 
statistics so would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess:

It might have something to do with the properties of the chi^2 distribution. Assuming that your failure rate is constant, each lifetime's time to failure is distributed as exponential. The sum of exponentials is distributed Erlang(Gamma with positive integer shape parameter). A Gamma random variable with shape = 1/2*shape and scale = 2 has a chi^2 distribution; the sample mean of chi^2 random variables is gamma.

Comment: The guess in the first paragraph is a good one.  The material in the second paragraph, though, does not appear to be relevant to the question and as such seems likely to confuse readers rather than enlighten them. Could you explain why "the normal distribution will be involved"? How does that square with the first paragraph which discusses decidedly *non* normal distributions?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the feedback! In the second paragraph, I was trying to make the connection between the normal distribution and chi^2 distribution(e.g. the sum of squared standard normal random variables) is distributed as chi^2. I was trying to say that since the sample space is only in the first quadrant, the standard normal distribution won't work because it's defined from (-inf, +inf) and you need (0, +inf). The chi^2 distribution fits this. I am not too clear how to express this, but that is what I have so far. Any tips? Should I go with a more rigorous approach?

Comment: @whuber A lognormal distribution also has support from (0, +inf).

Comment: That last comment is insightful, because it suggests there is no necessary connection between a quantity that is positive and a chi-squared distribution. In this particular case I think your first paragraph has fully captured the reason chi-squared distributions are involved--and that has nothing to do with any assumption of normality, nothing to do with the central limit theorem, etc. I would like to suggest you consider replacing the second paragraph with any thoughts you might have about addressing the second part of the question: what do you suppose justifies "more statistically accurate"?

Comment: Thanks for the help, muchas gracias. As I said I am fairly new to statistics so I was wondering can you maybe suggest a good source for the mathematics behind this relationship (maybe an online course). From what is said above, is the chi square distribution a special case of the gamma distribution where the beta parameter = 2? On a side not I am a physics graduate who was told that calculus was the only part of maths that matters. As I now start to explore other areas I am finding statistics fascinating

Comment: @user82989 I used wikipedia for looking up all the distributions, but I have a background in statistics so I already was aware of these relationships; wiki is still a good start though. If you are interested in a text book, I studied with "Statistical Inference 2nd Edition" by G. Casella and R. Berger, which goes over probability and statistics from a mathematically rigorous viewpoint. And yes, calculus is a big part of statistics, but it's not everything. When you get into theory of probability, you get into sigma algebra and subsets.

Comment: @user82989 And yes, statistics is fascinating. The plus side for you is you have a physics background, so the concepts of moments should be easier to understand. I actually wish I would have learned moments from a physical viewpoint(as the shape of a curve) first, and then go into what it's for versus learning it as a measure.

Comment: @whuber What justifies "more statistically accurate" to me is something that is statistically close to the true value of the dimension being measured. So, chi^2 is more "statistically accurate" since you are dealing with real data; the exponential distribution is a theoretical distribution, which most likely will not fit well with real data. Plausible?

Comment: Yes I think physics has provided me with fundamental knowledge of physical concepts that have many applications in many areas.

Comment: @small_data88  With regard to your discussion on the correlation between the exponential distribution and the observed data, for my application (Reliability Engineering), empirical evidence of the units involved shows that most units spend most of their operating life in the flat region of what is called a bathtub curve.

Comment: @small_data88 For most instruments/units/electrical components there is a high probability of failure upon first use (this due to manufacturing defects, commissioning etc.; this falls off quickly once initial operation is observed. Once up and running a flat region in the probability of failure as a function of time curve exists (working lifetime). Then as the unit reaches the end of its working life, there is a sharp rise in the probability of failure.

Comment: @ small_data88 As my units are up and running and nowhere the end of their working life, they are in the flat region. This implies a constant failure rate. My initial research into the topic (NIST Engineering Handbook) tells me that the only model that has a constant failure rate is the Homogeneous Poisson Process/exponential model. So the data is found the fit well to the model. I have only been looking into this for a couple of days so would love some feedback on my reasoning.

Comment: User82989 Since it looks like you found this answer helpful, then please consider upvoting it: that helps signal its usefulness quickly to other readers.

Comment: As I am new here, my rep doesn't allow yet.